# Django POST from links to the view that is not specified in URL

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

The page signup.html have url as shown

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('signup', views.Sign_up,name="signup"),
    ...
]
```

**signup.html**

```
<form class="signup-form initial-signup-form gtm_signup_register_form" action="." accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

But when the form is submitted instead of accessing Signup() view,it points to Login_view(). I got output as "invalid login details supplied!". But the expected output is home.html.

**views.py**

```
def Sign_up(request):
    Fname = request.POST.get("first_name")
    Lname = request.POST.get("last_name")
    Mno = request.POST.get("Mobile")
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    Pass = request.POST.get("pass")
    Role = request.POST.get("role")
    Loc = request.POST.get("self_loc")

    if request.method == "POST":
        userM = UserManager()
        if Role=="Consumer":
            userV= userM.create_user(Mno,Role,Pass)
        else:
            userV= userM.create_staffuser(Mno,Role,Pass)
        userV.first_name=Fname
        userV.last_name=Lname
        userV.email=email
        userV.location=Loc
        return render(request, "home.html", {})
    else:
        return render(request, "registration/signup.html", {})

def Login_view(request):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        Uname = request.POST.get("Mobile")
        PassW = request.POST.get("password")
        print(Uname, PassW)
        user = authenticate(mobile_no = Uname, password=PassW)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                if user.is_staff:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print("Mobile_no: {} and password {}".format(Uname,PassW))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supplied!")
    else:
        return render(request,"registration/login.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **signup.html** form's action attribute should point to `"signup"` instead of `.`

```
<form class="signup-form initial-signup-form gtm_signup_register_form" action="signup" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: in views.py , userV= userM.create_user(Mno,Role,Pass) and             mobile_no=mobile_no,
in models.py

Comment: post your create_user and are your sure all the data your are passing from form? most probably you are calling something on `Mno,Role,Pass` in create_user and it is None

Comment: model is added to the question

Comment: the "NoneType" error corrected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286352/typeerror-at-signup-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-in-django/55291192#55291192