# TypeError at /signup 'NoneType' object is not callable in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, typeerror, django-custom-user

Have custom User model, but using this model I can only create superuser using terminal command "python manage.py createsuperuser".

The error : "TypeError at /signup  'NoneType' object is not callable"

Traceback:
1

```
userV= userM.create_user(int(Mno),Role,Pass)
```

2

```
mobile_no=mobile_no,
```

**models.py**

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    object = UserManager()
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(_('MobNumber'), null=True, blank=True,unique=True)        
    role = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(_('Activated'), default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('is_admin'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('is_staff'), default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def Sign_up(request):
    Fname = request.POST.get("first_name")
    Lname = request.POST.get("last_name")
    Mno = request.POST.get("Mobile")
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    Pass = request.POST.get("pass")
    Role = request.POST.get("role")
    Loc = request.POST.get("self_loc")

    if request.method == "POST":
        userM = UserManager()
        if Role=="Consumer":
            userV= userM.create_user(int(Mno),Role,Pass)
        else:
            userV= userM.create_staffuser(int(Mno),Role,Pass)
        userV.first_name=Fname
        userV.last_name=Lname
        userV.email=email
        userV.location=Loc
        return render(request, "home.html", {})
    else:
        return render(request, "registration/signup.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these these two codes in views.py

```
userV= userM.create_user(int(Mno),Role,Pass)


userV= userM.create_staffuser(int(Mno),Role,Pass)
```

to

```
userV= Users.object.create_user(int(Mno),Role,Pass)

userV= Users.object.create_staffuser(int(Mno),Role,Pass)
```

We must reference Users model, where it is linked with UserManger.